# What strapping mechanism is this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

What should I google to find the strap from the picture?
It looks like a screw is used to tension the strap, which is exactly what I need. I've already spent some time trying to find a manufacturer who could supply these, yet unsuccessfully and I would appreciate your help!

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Check out terminology used in oil and gas industry: https://www.roblon.com/industries/offshore-oil-gas/straps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would go to a saddlemaker as they are good with leather, but a barrel maker may be a possibility, however there are few around now.

However, the parts may need sourcing but as a basic idea it is just a threaded rod and a nut - shaped etc so as to not damage the leather.

Comment: Thank you! However, I think that these are polyester webbing straps?

Comment: Well, difficult to tell from the poor image.

Comment: In that case, the straps can be seen in the following video:
https://youtu.be/CkqhSfsFxhg?t=84

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism that tensions the strap looks like maybe a *draw latch*, though it's a little hard to tell.

Some examples of this mechanism:
https://www.mcmaster.com/products/draw-latches/